# What happens if StreamReader or StreamWriter are not closed?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm working on an assignment for a professor that is strict about [LOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code). For this reason I'd like to do the following:

```
(new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName)).Write(textBox.Text);
```

instead of

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);
sw.Write(textBox.Text);
sw.Close();
```

In the first example I don't close the stream. Is this ok? Will it cause any security or memory problems?

Comment: No offense to you, but that's a really asinine requirement. I don't know of any legitimate company that says, "You can't write more than N lines of code for this project." What in the world is the use of teaching that way?

Comment: If the number of lines is that important for your tutor...maybe he should teach English instead.

Comment: i had an english professor, who awarded marks on LOC. Please tell your tutor that lesser LOC does not guarantee faster execution always.

Comment: @MichaelTodd i agree, that's why I feel annoyed on his teaching style.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may not get any output, or incomplete output. Closing the writer also flushes it. Rather than manually calling `Close` at all, I'd use a `using` statement... but if you're *just* trying to write text to a file, use a one-shot [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) call:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, textBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe your tutor is looking for:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, textbox.Text);
```

It's reasonable to prefer concise code, but not at the expense of readability or correctness.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution without fout.Close() should be:

```
        using (StreamWriter fout = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            fout.Write(textBox.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't close it, you can't guarantee that it'll write out the last piece of data written to it. This is because it uses a buffer and the buffer is flushed when you close the stream.

Second, it will lock the file as open preventing another process from using it.

The safest way to use a filestream is with a using statement.

Comment: +1 seems that mentioning the using statement is more apreciated then the actual straight answer.(not my personal opinion though) :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, the resources allocated for that operation will not be freed not to mention that it could pottentially lock that file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
using( var fout = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName){ fout.write(textBox.Text); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any how GC will close it for you. But the thing is until the GC closes that stream you are unnecessary putting on hold to the resources

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `using blok` in order to `clean your no managed object`

```
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(textBox.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a memory hazard.

I would always use StreamWriter in a 'using' statement

```
using(StreamWriter fout = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName)
{
    fout.Write(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: You also wouldn't be able to access that file in any other process until you close the StreamWriter.

Comment: so after using statement, it will be closed automatically, right?

Comment: @IvanLi It automatically disposes of the StreamWriting. Anything declared in a using statement is disposed of when the statement ends.

Comment: @Freeman Why would you not use implicit typing in this situation?

Comment: Because its more human readable and we are not doing JavaScript

Comment: @Freeman Ok, I guess thats just a matter of preference. I wouldn't agree that is is more readable. If was calling a method that was returning a type that is not obvious I would agree. But not when using a constructor.